# Can a form be submitted before the DOM is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, forms

I was considering loading a jQuery reference on a page after the DOM had loaded (`document.onload`) to speed up the page load of a page with a form *(It is my understanding that the DOM can finish before external script references have finished loading)*.

However, I was somewhat concerned that if a user was able to submit a form before jQuery had loaded my client-side validation would not be in place. That would leave only my server-side validation to prevent form submission abuse which feels less secure.

**So my question** is can a user submit a form as soon as the DOM is ready and therefore bypass my client-side validators that are not completed loading until `window.onload` fires?

Comment: you can enable the form submit button in the onload event

Comment: _That would leave only my server-side validation to prevent form submission abuse which feels less secure_ That's the one and only security you have! Anything on the client-side can be compromised.

Comment: there is no security in the browser in the first place. Client side validation is really only a convenience. technically yes user could submit before your script activates

Comment: It's so easy to tamper with data between your client-side validation scripts and the request to the server. 1) Don't rely on it, and use client side validation only to help the user and prevent unnecessary round-trips. 2) Make sure your site is still useable without javascript. It shouldn't all come crashing down when it is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...can a user submit a form as soon as the DOM is ready and therefore bypass my client-side validators..."?

Yes, for example: A user can easily save it, edit the form, remove any validation JavaScript, and then load that version in their browser. Then they can send whatever values they want to any of the parameters. Doing validation and reformatting on the server side can make sure the data is safe for use/storage. ([Like in the case of an SQL Injection attack...](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet))

I use client side validation mainly for interface design logic, like using a regex to determine if I should display `You forgot an @ in your email address.` on an email field. Never depend on a client to make the data benign.

Answer (score 2):

Server-side is the best way to validate and should be done regardless of any client-side validation. Notwithstanding, trigger your client-side validation when the user clicks submit and you should be ok.